# Alternatives of dealing with perfect collinearity in OLS Regression

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, prediction, regression-coefficients

I am running an OLS regression with hundreds of dummy variables. Some columns of the X matrix (design matrix) are linearly dependent on others. My question is, is the value of the fitted values (Y variable) dependent on which columns are dropped? Or can we rather say the vector of fitted value is unique? I believe which column(s) you drop should not matter, but looking for a proof of this.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you coded your dummies correctly.  For example, a categorial variable X with 2 possible values A and B, a dummy should be created for either A or B, **not both**: *D* = 1 if X = A and 0 otherwise.  Or *D* = 1 if X = B and 0 otherwise.  If 2 dummies are created, one for each value, then the dummies are linearly dependent and OLS just won't run.

Second, the fitted value of OLS is given by y = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + .... + bpXp.  Thus, it is clear that removing any of the X's (column) will result a change in y.

Finally, you should do some analysis before deciding what columns to remove rather than doing it arbitrarily.

Comment: Hello, I'm using the lm() function of R, which fits the largest-rank X matrix by removing columns (dummy variables) in reverse order of appearance, until the remaining columns are linearly independent. I meant to ask if y (the fitted value) would change, had R removed a different set of columns, say, not in reverse order of appearance, but in order of appearance. In other words, I'm curious if the y vector is unique.

Comment: @celine As I understand it, the question in your comment is directed at the inner workings of the `lm` function.  As such, I don't have an answer. But my bet is the fitted values won't change. Eg, given the observed Y and Xs, the fitted values can change if and only if the estimated coefficients change. That implies `lm` can provide more than 1 set of solution to the least square problem, which does not make sense to me.